# How to sort collection in my pre-defined order?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, guava

For example, I have next list of strings:

```
List<String> s = newArrayList("string", "someString", "anotherStr", "yetAnotherString", "Something");
```

I need to sort it in a special way, for example:
yetAnotherString, someString, anotherStr, string, Something

so there is no alphabetical or lexicographical ordering, in pseudo code it would like:

```
if (el == yetAnotherString)
{
 set order 1;
}
else if (someString)
{
 set order 2;
} ....
```

Do java Collections or guava allows doing such ordering?

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==` but `equals`

Comment: @Dici if you read carefully, you'll see, that the last code block is given as pseudo code. Though it doesn't make your advice less useful, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If such an ordering exists, then you should be able express it in a `Comparator`, ie: given two elements decide their order. And once you do so, you can pass your `Comparator` to the sort method

```
Collections.sort(list,comparator);
```

Comment: so, I need to write the relationship for all elements between each other ?

Comment: if you already know what the sorting order is, then directly add them to the arraylist. why to compare them at all? Therefore why comparator?

Comment: @premkumar this arraylist I gave only for an example, actually there is a difficult logic, so I can't put it directly, I need to order it after gaining a list

Comment: @JisforJava I don't quite understand your ordering criteria, but if it is based on constant strings then yes, you have to do it manually

Comment: @SleimanJneidi actually there is no criteria. As you've mentioned, I just need to compare it with constant strings

Comment: @SleimanJneidi as for the question about comparing all elements, I meant if I need to write if for first element with second, third, etc., then second element with third, fourth, etc. and so on ?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a list of which elements you want in which order, then Guava provides [`Ordering.explicit`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#explicit(T,%20T...)); you can pass in the order of the elements and then use that as a `Comparator` to sort.